# Google Shopping - Get product url after upload

Tags: google-shopping-api

Maybe somebody got the same question:

We're uploading products on Google Shopping using [Products Custom Batch Request](https://developers.google.com/shopping-content/v2/reference/v2/products/custombatch)

In response we got [Product Entity](https://developers.google.com/shopping-content/v2/reference/v2/products#resource) which didn't contains Google product ID or url on this product on Google Shopping.

Does anybody knows how to get link after uploading product?

Link example: https://www.google.com/shopping/product/564374406285262179 where *564374406285262179* is productID